# FindNext does not work with range (error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

This part of FindNext throws me error 1004, telling me that my range can not get the FindNext property. At first it was in form but I read that that could be the problem so I moved it to a module, still it still throwing the same error in the same part.

```
Sub list_click(ByVal Form As UserForm)
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim rRange As Range
    Count = Form.ListBox1.ListCount

    data = Sheets("IN").Range("AB6").Value
    Sheets("DB").Select
    Sheets("DB").Range("A2").Select
    Set rRange = Columns(1)

    For i = 0 To Count - 1
        If Form.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Index = form.ListBox1.List(i)

        End If
    Next i

    c = rRange.Find(What:=Index, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Activate

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) <> data Then
        c = rRange.FindNext(After:=c)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it should be `set c = rRange.FindNext(After:=c)` and there is a typo in `Interger` that should be `Integer`

Comment: I throw the error 13 Do not match the types, the error of the integer was a mistake to change some names, it is not in the original code

Comment: yes of course it should also be `Set c = rRange.Find(What:=Index, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)`. And I suggest to use `Option Explicit` as first statement in your module (outside the sub) to be forced to declare (with `dim`) any variables before use!

Comment: Thanks, add the set to both but still throw error 13

Comment: did you also remove the `.Activate` from that line? see my answer below

Comment: `Dim c As Range` , and after `c = rRange.Find(What:=Index, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)` , should not throw an error. Later, to confirm `Find` was successful, add `If Not c Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

Variables net to be set to objects with `a = set objB`

```
Option Explicit 'First line in every module. Forces you to declare variables before use!

Sub list_click(ByVal Form As UserForm)
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim rRange As Range, c As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Count = Form.ListBox1.ListCount


    Data = Sheets("IN").Range("AB6").Value
    Set rRange = Sheets("DB").Columns(1)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Count - 1
        If Form.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Index = Form.ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    Set c = rRange.Find(What:=Index, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) <> Data Then
        Set c = rRange.FindNext(After:=c)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Come on, you are better than this ;) remove the un-necessary `Sheets("DB").Select` , use  `Set rRange = Sheets("DB").Columns(1)`

`

Comment: Uh, yes of course didn't have my first coffee yet. Corrected.